# How to move object properly with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put two boxes next to each other but so far the second object is always below the first one. This is the code that I am using from *getbootstrap.com*.

I just need to boxes like this one two appear nexto to each other not on different lines. Note: I've tried using this in CSS
`float: left;` sadly nothing good has happened.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you only have one box. You should do some reading on the columns idea that is behind the twitter bootstrap grid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro.

I'm assuming you're trying to get a mixture of behaviour for both mobile and desktop (by mixing the col-xs and col-md which are different cell sizes).

```
<!-- make both columns same length one next to the other -->
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">.col-md-4</div>
 </div>
```

.col-xs-12 .col-md-8
      .col-xs-6 .col-md-4

```
<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Another question how can I do the same thing but with different elements. I mean I have a Carousel and I want to put another box next to it but this rule is not working. DO you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this 
http://www.layoutit.com/build

```
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
"Box" 1
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
"Box" 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: True.  Just throwing up a quick answer based on the level of experience the poster mentioned. :-)